# Dual of compact operator and dimension of dual space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

[The trace class operators are the dual of the compact operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654861/the-trace-class-operators-are-the-dual-of-the-compact-operators)

It is proved that dual of space of compact operator $K(H)$ is space of trace class operator $L_1(H)$.

Now, $L_1(H) \subseteq K(H)$, but for infinite dimensional spaces we know that Hamel dimension of dual space is strictly greater than dimension of space.

How it is consistent with this fact in case $H$ infinite dimensional?

Comment: Short answer: You're mixing up algebraic (all linear functionals) and topological (all continuous linear functionals) duals.