# Dual of space of compact linear operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

For a Hilbert space $H$, consider the space of compact linear operators on this Hilbert space, $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$.

Is it correct to say that the dual space of $\mathcal{K}(H)$ is the space of trace-class linear operators on the same Hilbert space, $B_1(H)$? Conversely, is the dual of $B_1(H)$ given by $\mathcal{K}(H)$?

Comment: [The trace class operators are the dual of the compact operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654861).

Comment: Thank you! How about the other way around? Is the dual of trace-class operators given by compact operators?